# Using meta, metaprop, and forest to create forest plot graphics in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I am using the metaprop command in R to do a meta-analysis of proportions. Some sample code is below.

```
library(meta)
m <- metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40))
forest(m)
```

[image: Forest plot]

I have several questions.

1. How do I force all of the text (proportion column, 95% CI column, fixed and random weights columns) to appear on the LEFT side of the plot rather than on the right?
2. I have another column of text identifiers for each study that I would like to add on the left as well. How can I stick this in as its own column?
3. I really need to plot these as percentages, not proportions. Is there a way to make this change?
4. Last, I need the bottom axis to go from 0 to 100% and have a label.

**Edit**

Ok, I have figured out how to do almost everything. The only thing I need help with is, I have another vector of labels that I would like to add to the left side of the plot. It seems like the leftlabs or leftcols command should do this but I can't get it to work. I would like to also plot another column on the left entitled "Details" that, for each of the four studies, has a little sentence about them.

```
forest(m, xlim = c(0,100), pscale = 100, weight = "random", leftcols = c("studlab", "event", "n", "effect", "ci", "w.random"), rightcols = F, leftlabs = c("Study", "Number", "Total", "Prevalence (%)", "95% CI", "Weight"), xlab = "Prevalence (%)", addspace = TRUE, digits = 1, squaresize = 0.5, text.I2 = "I2", text.tau2 = "tau2")
```

[image: Second Forest Plot]

Comment: There is a pending edit on this post about removing `sas` and `stata` from the tags which I would have also done on my own. Please remove unrelated tags. Why do people specializing in sas or stata need to visit this question? This has nothing to do with these languages.

Comment: There are no tags for "epidemiology," "biostatistics," or "meta-analysis," and many researchers who use SAS and Stata also use R, so I put the tags there because I assume that they would be highly correlated with the non-existent "epidemiology" and "biostatistics" tags... Just trying to get the right people to look at my question.

Comment: With all due respect, I believe that assumption violates the intended use of tags. If people that use SAS and Stata, also use R, and are interested in answering/reading questions on R, they would follow the R tag. I don't think there's a need for additional tags based on correlations.

Comment: And while the question has to do with an epidemiological topic (meta-analysis), the contents of the question are very R-specific ("How to do this in R?"). On that subject, you can either comb trough all options for the forest function and try to adapt it, or try to create your own plot.

Comment: But my statistical side loves correlations! Anyway, point taken. Anyone have a clue on adding another column??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
# https://rdrr.io/cran/meta/man/forest.html

# See the example in the link above, specifically 

data(Olkin95)
meta1 <- metabin(event.e, n.e, event.c, n.c,
                 data=Olkin95, subset=c(41,47,51,59),
                 sm="RR", method="I",
                 studlab=paste(author, year))

#
# Specify column labels only for newly created variables
# 'year' and 'author' (which are part of dataset Olkin95)
#
forest(meta1,
       leftcols=c("studlab", "event.e", "n.e", "event.c", "n.c",
                  "author", "year"),
       leftlabs=c("Author", "Year of Publ"))
```