# Issues with metaprop a function of meta in R

Tags: r

I am working through the solved example linked here. Everything works except for the "Weight" column which displays the data from the w.random variable in the metaprop output as you will see in the code.

[Using meta, metaprop, and forest to create forest plot graphics in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655316/using-meta-metaprop-and-forest-to-create-forest-plot-graphics-in-r)

```
library(meta)
m <- metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40))
forest(m, xlim = c(0,100), pscale = 100, weight = "random", leftcols = c("studlab", "event", "n", "effect", "ci", "w.random"), rightcols = F, leftlabs = c("Study", "Number", "Total", "Prevalence (%)", "95% CI", "Weight"), xlab = "Prevalence (%)", addspace = TRUE, digits = 1, squaresize = 0.5, text.I2 = "I2", text.tau2 = "tau2")
```

[image]

As you can see in the column the Weight column is "--" for each row.

When I check the value of the variable m$w.random you can see that is all NA. The variable m$w.random should = 27.3, 27.7, 25.4, 19.6 per the link

```
> m$w.random
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

**EDIT** per bobloblawlawblog

```
m <- metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40), method = "Inverse")
> m$w.random
[1] 0.6208545 0.6304480 0.5781246 0.4505199
```

This is helpful I think but I am unsure what this output means?

Comment: Could you try adding `method = "Inverse"` to metaprop()?

Comment: @bobloblawlawblog This gave me numbers, which is great! but what are they? What are they the inverse off?

Comment: I am not familiar with this package, but I found this information [here](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/pooling-es.html#pooling-props). If I understood correctly, you can either specify ML or Inverse-variance weighing for pooling. If I had to guess, the function in that package version defaults to "Inverse" for the question you linked, which was asked a while ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the author of the package and he responded with the following:

> The default method in metaprop() has changed with meta, version 4.9-5 (2019-04-11). A generalised linear mixed model (GLMM) is used instead of the classic normal approximation. Only downside is that the software for GLMMs does not provide individual study weights. We discuss this in Schwarzer et al. (2019).

> You could use the following command to reproduce the results on the Stackoverflow website:
> summary(metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40), method = "Inverse", method.tau = "DL"))

> The REML estimator (method.tau = "REML") is the default since meta, version 5.0-0 (2021-10-11). Accordingly, argument method.tau = "DL" is needed to choose the DerSimonian-Laird estimator to reproduce the results for the random effects model.

The solution is:

```
summary(metaprop(4:1, c(10, 20, 30, 40), method = "Inverse", method.tau = "DL"))
```